# Does undefined check ever throw an error in JavaScript without typeof in IE6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I don't have an access to IE6 right now, so, I am asking here.

If I have a comparison such as:

```
// imagine App being declared as an obj somewhere...
if (App.errorLog === undefined) {
    App.errorLog = [];
}
```

Would that code throw an error in IE6 if the property was never declared or defined anywhere? It seems to work fine in other browsers even in IE7. I just think that I had some problems with IE6 while a back and used `typeof` to solve those problems, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties that were not set will simply return the value of [`undefined`](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#undefined). Only undeclared variables will actually raise a `ReferenceError`, this is where you then have to use `typeof foo === 'undefined'`.

So yes, your code will work.

Comment: Why is not errorLog undeclared in this case? Because it is part of an object?

Comment: @rFactor The *property* is *not defined* on the object. This is different from an *undeclared* variable. It's simply part of the language design to return `undefined` in such a case instead of raising an error.

Answer (score 1):

works fine in IE6 as you have it

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof` trick resolves issues where the global `undefined` has been overwritten, or where a *variable* has not been declared.

In your case, you're just checking for the existence of a *property* in the `App` object. As long as `App` exists, there shouldn't be a declaration issue.

If there's a chance that some code will overwrite `undefined`, then you need `typeof`.

Another way to test for a property is:

```
if ( !('errorLog' in App) ) {
    App.errorLog = [];
}
```

This will also look at members of the `prototype`, and so is equivalent to checking for `undefined` and it gets around the issue of `undefined` being overwritten.

Comment: So, errorLog is still declared, because it's a property of an object? In which cases this might not be true?

Comment: @rFactor: Not sure what you mean. If you're talking about `!('errorLog' in App)`, that's just another way to test for `undefined`. If `App` does not have a property called `errorLog`, then the statement is `true`, and `App.errorLog = [];` will execute.

Answer (score 0):

i believe it would not throw an exception but simply it would go out of the if condition.
also i have not heard of undefined as value.
if you are trying to say that if the App.errorlog is not set then the code should be
App.errorlog == null.